# Is it possible to limit current by some amount of amperes?

Tags: batteries, current, battery-charging, current-limiting

I have an accumulator that has a maximum charging current of 3A. The battery connected to solar panel for charging and invertor for discharging. Solar panel can give for i.e. 10A, so, I want to send 3A to battery and 7A to invertor.

Is it possible to limit the maximum current that go to battery and send the difference to the load?

Comment: Probably easier to program the inverter to draw the correct amount of current to leave 3 A leftover for battery charging.

Comment: @Neil_UK Is it impossible?

Comment: It's impossible in the sense that you can't 'send the difference to the load', for arbitrary loads. You can only 'send power to' low or zero impedance loads, like a battery that requires charging. If you have a grid-tied inverter that's selling power to the grid, then you can ask that to supply more to the grid, but you can't just 'send more power' to it. If the load is something like a kettle, or a freezer, then what you do is fix the source voltage, and the load draws the power it wants to.